# Find domain of $ \sin ^ {-1} [\log_2(\frac{x}{2})]$

Tags: functions

> **Problem**:  Find domain of $ \sin ^ {-1} [\log_2(\frac{x}{2})]$
>
> **Solution**: $\log_2(\frac{x}{2})$ is defined for $\frac{x}{2} > 0$
>
> $\log_2(\frac{x}{2})$ is defined for $x > 0$
>
> Also domain of $\sin ^ {-1}x$ is $[-1,1]$
>
> When $x=1$ ,then $\log_2(\frac{x}{2})$ becomes $-1$
>
> When $x=4$ ,then $\log_2(\frac{x}{2})$ becomes $1$
>
> So domain is $[1,4]$

Comment: Is $[.]$ the floor function?

Comment: No , I used it for square bracket

Comment: Check the graph. I think it is $\pi/2$ to positive infinity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

You can search the proper $x$ in which we can have $$\log_2(x/2)\in[-1,+1], ~~\text{and}~~~x/2>0$$ simultaneously. Note that the logarithm function is a one-one function here.

Comment: It is also monotone increasing, which facilitates handling inequalities.

Comment: @rst: When $-1\le\log_2(x/2)\le 1 $ then according to comment below my answer you can write $2^{-1}\le x/2\le 2^1$

Comment: Thanks, now it's more clear to me

Answer (score 1):

the domain is [1,4] as sin (y) is between -1 &1

Comment: Can you explain in some more detail ?

Answer (score 1):

here log(x/2) should be between -1&1 because if arc sin a=b then

sin (b)=a or a is between -1 &1

Comment: You could make your previous answer fixed. :)